# In PHP, after assigning a file pointer resource to a variable with fopen(), how can I get the file name from the variable?

Tags: php, file

For example:

```
$file = fopen("File.txt", "r");
$filename = $file->basename;
```

if there was a method like basename for file objects (file pointer resources).

Comment: You obviously know the file name if you 'fopen'ed it.  Why do you need to get it from the fopen variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, there is not a method to do. You should rather store the filename in a variable, like this:

```
<?php
$filename = "File.txt";
$file = fopen($filename, "r");
$basename = basename($filename);
```

Also, a little side note: a file pointer is **not** an object, it is a resource, which you can see by passing it to `var_dump()` (it would output something like `resource(3) of type (stream)`). This means that you cannot use it directly, you would have to use functions from the PHP core or a PHP extension to handle it. In the case of file pointers, you would use functions like `fread()`, `fwrite()`  and `fclose()` to do so.

Answer (score 5):

**No, there is not.**

By the way, in which scenario is this thing needed?

Answer (score 4):

I came to this page while trying to find out the filename that PHP's `tmpfile()` function had created - it returns a pointer. I wanted to use it to create a file I could use with some Unix commands. In the end I used `tempnam(realpath(sys_get_temp_dir()), "piclib_");` instead.