# How to get more info about a resource?

Tags: php, file, resources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In PHP, after assigning a file pointer resource to a variable with fopen(), how can I get the file name from the variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621681/in-php-after-assigning-a-file-pointer-resource-to-a-variable-with-fopen-how)

Example:

`$this->resource = fopen('c:\wamp\www\some_file.txt', 'a');`

Now if I try to access `$this->resource` later, in a different method I get:

`Resource id #51: stream`

Can I get the actual file path too?

Comment: how can you not know what file you are opening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in addtitional aswer with voodoo417, you can get info about the file like this

```
$infos = pathinfo('/www/htdocs/inc/lib.inc.php');

echo $infos ['dirname'], "\n";
echo $infos ['basename'], "\n";
echo $infos ['extension'], "\n";
echo $infos ['filename'], "\n";
```

----------------------   OUTPUT   -------------------------

```
/www/htdocs/inc
lib.inc.php
php
lib.inc
```

//from php.net

also see fileinfo extention.

Answer (score 1):

This is not file path , this is link on opened file. And it work normally. Now you can work with this resource ( file in this context ).